# Rigidity Criterion (Thompson/Belyi/Matzat).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, galois-theory, simple-groups

Just a quick one. I've been sifting through many sources and found different definitions of rigidity when it comes to finite simple groups. I was hoping for some clarification.

http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~raw/pubs_files/sgensweb.pdf

In this paper (under heading 3), the author defines a group to be rationally rigid if the "symmetrized structure constant" $\xi_G = 1$ (as defined page 3) and $g_1g_2g_3 = 1$.

On the other hand, if one looks at this question here: [Possible repeated conjugacy classes in Thompson's Rigidity Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281865/possible-repeated-conjugacy-classes-in-thompsons-rigidity-criterion)

we see that no mention is made of the symmetrized structure constant, only that if such a rigid tuple $(g_1,g_2,g_3)$ exists, then for any other tuple $(g^{'}_1,g^{'}_2,g^{'}_3)$ then there exists some unique $g$ such that the two tuples are conjugate.

Lastly, if we consider the following, [Rigidity of conjugacy classes of finite centerless groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603134/rigidity-of-conjugacy-classes-of-finite-centerless-groups)
, Serre speaks of rigidity in terms of the group G acting transitively on some set $\Sigma$ with the desired properties of the group $G$.

I was just wondering whether these definitions were in fact equivalent. That is, for Thompson's Rigidity Criterion for the case of a triple generating system, would it be enough to have that a finite group $G$ is generated by $g_1,g_2,g_3$ such that $g_1g_2g_3=1$ with each $g_i$ $\in C_i$. I feel as if there's an extra condition that I am missing since each other three individual definitions impose a further condition.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think the structure constant is used in determining rational rigidity?